# The method getString(int) is undefined for the type Apps

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, getstring

How do I fix this error. All the three strings on the bottom get the following error "the method getString(int) is undefined for the type Apps". Please help, im such a noob.

```
package com.actionbarsherlock.sample.fragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;


public final class Apps {
/**
 * Our data, part 1.
 */
public static final String[] TITLES =
{
        "title1",
        "title2",
        "title3"
};

/**
 * Our data, part 2.
 */
public static final String[] DIALOGUE = { 

    getString(R.string.text1),

    getString(R.string.string2),

    getString(R.string.string3)

};
}
```

Comment: You're trying to call a non-existent method.  There's really not much we can do to help you fix it without knowing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are you meaning to extend something? What are you trying to subclass?

Comment: the person helping me with this said "getString is from the activity class, so your class needs to inherit from activity, or you need to call getString from a class that already inherits from activity."

Comment: What im trying to do is call those three strings they hold text value

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First `getString` is not a static method, you are calling it in a static context this can't be done.

Second the `getString` method is part of the `Resources` class, your class does not extend the `Resources` class so the method can't be found.

I think parsing an instance of the `Resources` class to your `Apps` class using its constructor would be your the best option.

Something like this:

```
public final class Apps {

    public Apps(Resources r){
     DIALOGUE = new String[]{
        r.getString(R.string.text1),
        r.getString(R.string.string2),
        r.getString(R.string.string3)};
    }


/**
 * Our data, part 1.
 */
public static final String[] TITLES =
{
        "title1",
        "title2",
        "title3"
};

/**
 * Our data, part 2.
 */
public static String[] DIALOGUE;
}
```

Comment: Got rid of the error but I have to fix something else I'll brb with the results :)

Comment: mhhh when i select a category then app title the app force closes. Ill play around more but your answer was the most helpful.

Answer (score 32):

pass a instance of `Context context`

and then use

```
context.getResources().getString(R.string.text1)
```

here `context` is belongs to your current activity.

Comment: I followed this and rewrote Preferences.getBoolean(getString(R.string.pref_mypreference), false) to Preferences.getBoolean(***getContext().***getString(R.string.pref_mypreference), false) and Bob became my uncle :D (the *** are not literal, but showing what changed only) ;)

Answer (score 2):

Create a subclass of Application, for instance public class App extends Application {
    Set the android:name attribute of your  tag in the AndroidManifest.xml to point to your new class, e.g. android:name=".App"
    In the onCreate() method of your app instance, save your context (e.g. this) to a static field named mContext and create a static method that returns this field, e.g. getContext():

This is how it should look:

```
public class App extends Application{

    private static Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = this;
    }

    public static Context getContext(){
        return mContext;
    }
}
```

Now you can use: App.getContext().getString()

Answer (score 1):

you could try

```
getResources().getString(R.string.somestrid);
```

or

```
getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.somestrid);
```